# How to import pfx certificate and set private key permissions for all users

Tags: windows, ssl, certificate, pfx, certutil

I have self-signed pfx certificate, and machine with 2 users (A and B). I need to install the certificate using some command line tool and it should be available for all users.

In case user A installs the certificate manually in LocalMachine\My or LocalMachine\Root it is available only for user A because user B doesn't have private key permissions.

I tried

```
winhttpcertcfg.exe -i cert.pfx -p pass -a Everyone -c LOCAL_MACHINE\Root
```

but it doesn't help, certificate is available only for user that runs winhttpcertcfg.

I tried

```
winhttpcertcfg.exe -i cert.pfx -p pass -a Everyone -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My
```

but it installs the certificate in Root instead of My regardless -c parameter.

I tried

```
certutil -f -p pass -importpfx "cert.pfx"
```

but it doesn't help, certificate is available only for user that runs certutil.

In case My store the issue can be fixed manually:

- Right click on the certificate in Local Machine Cert Manager -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys
- Add users A and B and set necessary permissions.

But I need some automatic way that I will use while installing my applications.

Answer (score 0):

To import certificate you can use this powershell command

```
Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certFilename cert:$certStoreLocation -Password $mypwd
```

and use this for managing permissions

[How to Grant permission to user on Certificate private key using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046916/how-to-grant-permission-to-user-on-certificate-private-key-using-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Import-PfxCertificate has been giving me issues when trying to grant permissions to the private key.  The returned certificate and the certificate object grabbed using the

```
cert:\LocalMachine\My
```

both have null on the private key property.

I have to use a x509 certificate store and x509certifcate2 object to import the certificate and private key.  Then I'm able to change the private key permissions in powershell